# How to read file from internal storage when Android app starts

Tags: android, file, save, internal-storage

I have a button which saves changes, and put this in internal storage, then when app starts I want to read the file if there is any ofc. I thought that would be enough but I'm fresh coder and don't know that is good.

I don't know where is mistake, and also that is good code, please help me because I am stuck

My code:

```
public class MyGameDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
  
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_game_details, container, false);


        try {
            FileInputStream is = getActivity().openFileInput(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
           
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            is.close();
        } catch(OutOfMemoryError om) {
            om.printStackTrace();
          

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
           
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
        saveBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.savechangesbtn);
       saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Data1 = s1.getText().toString();
                Data2 = s2.getText().toString();
                Data3 = s3.getText().toString();
                Data4 = s4.getText().toString();
                Data5 = s5.getText().toString();
                Data6 = s6.getText().toString();


                try {

                    FileOutputStream fos=getActivity().openFileOutput(file, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    outputStream.write(Data1.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(Data2.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(Data3.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(Data4.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(Data5.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(Data6.getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                   
                    //Toast.makeText(context,"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                try {
                    FileInputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput(file);
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
               
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line);
                    }
                    r.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        });

        return view;



 }
}
```

Ps: s1,s2 etc. are created in code etc.

Permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would suggest you that, Dont write code in OnCreateView() method in fragments, always write code in OnViewCreated method.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_game_details, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        try {
        FileInputStream is = getActivity().openFileInput(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        is.close();
    } catch(OutOfMemoryError om) {
        om.printStackTrace();


    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    saveBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.savechangesbtn);
   saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Data1 = s1.getText().toString();
            Data2 = s2.getText().toString();
            Data3 = s3.getText().toString();
            Data4 = s4.getText().toString();
            Data5 = s5.getText().toString();
            Data6 = s6.getText().toString();


            try {

                FileOutputStream fos=getActivity().openFileOutput(file, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                outputStream.write(Data1.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data2.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data4.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data5.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data6.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();

                //Toast.makeText(context,"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            try {
                FileInputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput(file);
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
                r.close();
                inputStream.close();
                Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    });
}
```

If you are facing any error, then Please write the stacktrace of error.

Thanks

**Cheers!! Simplicity is the best!**

Comment: I dont have any errors, i got issues that this text dosent show up with app start, maby after close app this file is also deleted ?

Only in consloe 

09-15 07:59:24.604 1647-1661/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-15 07:59:24.604 1647-1661/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1

Comment: And also need line with check that file is in internal storage if not loda with normal View

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Other = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Details);
    OtherD = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.OtherDetails);



    try {
        FileInputStream is = getActivity().openFileInput(file);
        byte[] input = new byte[is.available()];
        while(is.read(input) != -1){


            value += new String(input);
        }
        is.getFD().sync();
        //is.flush();
        is.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] strArray =  value.split(";");

    s1.setText(strArray[1]);
    s2.setText(strArray[2]);
    s3.setText(strArray[3]);
    s4.setText(strArray[4]);
    s5.setText(strArray[5]);
    s6.setText(strArray[6]);
    s7.setText(strArray[7]);






    saveBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.savechangesbtn);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Data1 = s1.getText().toString();

            Data2 = s2.getText().toString();
            Data3 = s3.getText().toString();
            Data4 = s4.getText().toString();
            Data5 = s5.getText().toString();
            Data6 = s6.getText().toString();
            Data7=  s7.getText().toString();


            try {

                FileOutputStream fos=getActivity().openFileOutput(file, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data1.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data2.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data4.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data5.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data6.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Data7.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(string3.getBytes());
                //outputStream.getFD().sync();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                //Toast.makeText(context,"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            try {
                FileInputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput(file);
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
                r.close();
                inputStream.close();
                Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    });


}
```

Solve it on my own